# Room How to get 2 entities as 1 live data list?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-room

I want to get 2 different entities as 1 **LiveData** List
so that I could show them in a **RecyclerView**
and update it on data changes

Comment: Try to create custom Adapter for recyclerview and manipulate the data and views as you want.

Comment: You can Use [MediatorLiveData](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/lifecycle/MediatorLiveData.html).

Comment: I use RxJava / RxKotlin for mapping, combining and zipping my streams. For RxJava there are libraries to use it with room and with livedata (and retrofit as well). The Room database returns an observable of list<entities> (2 separate entities, so you have 2 observables). Using `Observables.combineLatest()` you get a new stream with the latest values of both queries (as a pair), which you can map to something else if you want. Using `LiveDataReactiveStreams.fromPublisher()` you can convert that to a LiveData. If any of the room queries updates the livedata will be updated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you have 2 room entities, both with one value, in it's own dao.
You want to combine those to a list (with up to 2 items) that can be observed as liveData.

I would go with a MediatorLiveData, get the entities as liveData from Room, and combine them like this:

```
class SomeClass {
    private val list1: LiveData<Something> = dao1.getLiveSomething()
    private val list2: LiveData<Something> = dao2.getOtherLiveSomething()
    private val _combinedList = MediatorLiveData<List<Something>>().apply{
        addSource(list1){
            value = listOfNotNull(it, list2.value)
        }
        addSource(list2){
            value = listOfNotNull(list1.value, it)
        }
    }

    /**
     * Observe this for combined list
     */
    val combinedList: LiveData<List<Something>>
        get() = _combinedList
}
```

This way, when one of the entities in Room get changed, `combinedList` will send the new data to any observers.